# Can non-consumable in-app purchases persist across app logins?

Tags: android, ios

I'm not sure if anyone can help. My team are looking to implement non-consumable in-app purchases on Android and iOS. How would this scenario work?

User logged into our app and makes a purchase non-consumable, i.e. a level pack for example. For whatever reason they lose their account details, decide to make a new account (same device and same iTunes / google account), can they use "restore purchases" with the new account to get access to the paid content? or does it need to be decoupled like with subscriptions to Tinder?

Cheers,

Comment: You have a lot of info about that in this [post](https://hackernoon.com/swift-how-to-add-in-app-purchases-in-your-ios-app-c1dc2fc82319) , and the offical apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase)

Answer (score 0):

For Android - It can only persists across logins if you are using same Gmail or google play account.
For Ios -  Apple follows the same thing. Need to remember the apple id.

You have to fetch that details from respective play store and apple store.

For more information check [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/243400/how-to-restore-in-app-purchases-on-android/) article.